# Error while printing the given inputs

Tags: c

This code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct my_structure {
    char name[20];
    int number;
    int rank;
};
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct my_structure variable[n];
    struct my_structure *ptr;
    ptr = &variable;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",ptr->name);
        scanf("%d",&ptr->number);
        scanf("%d",&ptr->rank);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("NAME: %s\n", ptr->name);
        printf("NUMBER: %d\n", ptr->number);
        printf("RANK: %d", ptr->rank);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is not printing correctly. I want to print the 1st input first and then the second. But I'm getting the output like printing only the second input two times.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes you need to do:-

```
ptr = variable ;
```

Then you can increase `ptr` in loop.(The use of `scanf` is not robust - how to do it better is shown in the end of the answer).

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",ptr->name);
    scanf("%d",&ptr->number);
    ...
    ptr++;
}
```

After that again do the assignment `ptr = variable;`.

You can also do this (Illustration on the users code)

```
    ..
    scanf("%s",ptr[i].name);
    scanf("%d",&ptr[i].number);
    ...
    printf("%s",ptr[i].name);
    printf("%d",ptr[i].number);
```

Earlier you have type mismatch in assignment. You were assigning a `struct my_structure (*)[n]` to `struct my_structure*`. Check the return value of `scanf` and also check the value `n` `(n>1)`.

You can do it on your  way also:(Illustration on the users code)

```
struct my_structure (*ptr)[n] = &variable;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",(*ptr)[i].name);
    scanf("%d",&((*ptr)[i].number));
    scanf("%d",&((*ptr)[i].rank));
}
...
    printf("%s",(*ptr)[i].name);
    printf("%d",((*ptr)[i].number));
```

Correct way to use `scanf` would be:-(Notice that here `19` is used - otherwise there is a chance of buffer overrun - and this is being checked using this.This is one less than the size of the array because of the `\0` character ) (Correct way)

```
if(scanf("%19s",ptr[i].name) != 1){
    /* error in input */
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Compile your program with all warnings enabled. `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`.

---

Clearly you don't even need to use this pointer - why would you do that? You can simply use the array itself in the `scanf` or `printf`.

Comment: @VinothViru.: What did you try?

Comment: pls copy my code and redesign it and post..i m getting some errors

Comment: @VinothViru.: With the answer privided you can do it yourself

Comment: okay..in which loop i have to use that ptr++..either in scanf loop or in printf loop ?

Comment: @VinothViru.: Where you are using only `ptr` not `ptr[i]` or anything. get a book.

Comment: struct my_structure (*ptr)[n]=&variable;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",(*ptr)[i].name);
        scanf("%d",&((*ptr)[i].number));
        scanf("%d",&((*ptr)[i].rank));
    }
        
    
    ptr = variable;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("NAME: %s\n", ptr[i].name);
        printf("NUMBER: %d\n", ptr[i].number);
        printf("RANK: %d", ptr[i].rank);
    }
 
P.S;this is the thing u told me change right?

Comment: @VinothViru.: You should use it in `printf` like the way I showed you.. `printf("RANK: %d", (*ptr)[i].rank);` and similar for other case.

Comment: it is working..thank you so much for your patience:)

Comment: @VinothViru.: Get a book...it will help you in long run.